# minimum subset which forms a given number from array dynamic programming python

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, dynamic, dynamic-programming

*LOOKING FOR DP RECURSIVE WAY TY*

task question: given a target number and an array of positive integers, print the minimum subset which sum of its element give you back target number
i.e.  `f(7, [1, 2, 3, 4, 7]) => [7]` 
`f(8, [3, 5, 8]) => [8]` 
`f(8, [1, 3, 5]) => [3, 5]` 
so far I built up an algorithm which gives you the minimum number of operation to reach target number

```py
def bestSum(targetSum, numbers, memo = {}):
    if targetSum in memo: return memo[targetSum]
    if targetSum == 0: return 0
    if targetSum < 0: return None
    Shortest = None
    for n in numbers:
        remainder = bestSum(targetSum - n, numbers, memo)
        if remainder != None:
            remainder+= 1
            if (Shortest == None or remainder < Shortest):
                Shortest = remainder
    memo[targetSum] = Shortest
    return Shortest
print(bestSum(20, [2, 5])) #4
input()
```

**precise question:**
*write a function "bestSum(targetSum, numbers)" that takes in a targetSum and an array of numbers as arguments.
the function should return an array containing the shortest combination of numbers that add up to exactly the targetSum*

Comment: what's your question precisely ?

Comment: @dallonsi just edited ;)

Comment: Why recursive way? I am not sure, but recursive solution might not be the most efficient solution one for this problem.

Comment: @AKSingh I'd like to visualize it as it were a tree. I am able to count the minimum number of operation but unable to print the that "numbered" array :(. P.S: obviously DP tree ;)

Comment: *"LOOKING FOR DP RECURSIVE WAY TY"*: I will ignore the ALLCAPS here, but if you are looking for a recursive way, then you should at least show your efforts in writing a recursive solution, and show where you are stuck with it. There is currently no trace of any effort to write a recursive solution.